# Condor submit to OSG with cctools/work_queue

Tags: condor

I am using HTCondor and I would like to submit jobs to the Open Science Grid. I am using cctools work_queue and to submit jobs to OSG UW Madison chtc documentation says to add `+WantFlocking = true` and `+WantGlideIn = true` to the submit file, the same where the universe (vanilla) is specified.

Can anyone tell me if this is the right submit file to modify? https://github.com/cooperative-computing-lab/cctools/blob/master/work_queue/src/condor_submit_workers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTCondor is configured differently by the administrators of the given HTCondor cluster, and these differences can be significant. Specifically, any submit file lines starting with a "+" are specific to the local HTCondor configuration.

Can you contact your local support team at UW-Madison for help. That's probably your best bet. (Full disclosure: I am one of the people on that team.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with work_queue, but I think you have found the right code to modify. This code isn't a submit file itself, but a script that generates a submit file, when I then assume work_queue gives to condor_submit. Inserting those custom attributes after `+JobMaxSuspendTime = 0` in the script should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! Which file is that?

Comment: The script you mentioned in your post, https://github.com/cooperative-computing-lab/cctools/blob/master/work_queue/src/condor_submit_workers

Comment: I would check with the CHTC facilitators to see why those attributes aren't being passed. They may also know someone more familiar with cctools...